# Is there any way to execute .aspx files inside the scope of the ASP.NET core app?

Tags: asp.net, forms, asp.net-core, iis

I have a situation where some users can create .aspx scripts and then paste on the ASP.NET app in IIS server to run it. I've rewrited the app to use ASP.NET Core that does not know .aspx files. Is there any way to execute .aspx files inside the scope of the ASP.NET core app?
What are the options without using another IIS site to run the .aspx files

Comment: WebForms (.aspx) is no longer updated, so unless you help yourself to reimplement it for .NET Core, there isn't another option other than using another site.

Comment: Nope, there isn't. You might be able to do something advanced using url rewrite to run 2 sites side by side within IIS but it could get complicated

Comment: @davidfowl Good to know. I'll take another direction

Comment: what are my options running a razor page (copy paste a razor page in the site). is possible calling a page directly without a controller?